# git-svn: Losing author in svn log after git svn dcommit

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm learning git-svn currently and it looks like SVN loses the author after I do `git svn dcommit`. When I look in the svn log, the commit is there but with no author.

I've read about this `authors.txt` file, and learnt how to tell git about it but my efforts didn't work.

My global `.gitconfig` file contains:

```
[svn]
    authorsfile = C:\\path\\to\\authors.txt
```

And my `authors.txt` file contains:

```
Joe = Joe Bloggs <joe.bloggs@example.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU authors file works when fetching data from svn to git, that is svn's `Joe` will become `Joe Bloggs <joe.bloggs@example.com>`. The feature won't work the other way around. All commits pushed back to svn via `git svn dcommit` will be identified by the committing svn user.

Comment: I'm not sure why but this issue resolved itself when I moved from testing it on my local machine to using it at work. Not sure what the difference is but atleast it works where it needs to!